# How can I use "react-native-android-pip"?

Tags: react-native

How can I use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-pip
I want to make a webview app can use PIP(Picture in Picture). But Idk how can I use this module in my code.

```html
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import AndroidPip from 'react-native-android-pip';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: '(My url)' }} style={{ marginTop: 50 }} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://github.com/shaun-chiang/rn-android-pip/blob/master/README.md) (On the documentation itself), You can use as follow:

```
import AndroidPip from 'react-native-android-pip';


// Enter Pip mode
AndroidPip.enterPictureInPictureMode() 

//Configure aspect ratio, works only on SDK version 26 and above
AndroidPip.configureAspectRatio(width, height) 


// When enabled, PIP mode will be automatically entered when app is unfocused( User presses home
//, menu button etc)
AndroidPip.enableAutoPipSwitch()
AndroidPip.disableAutoPipSwitch()
```

You can call these functions on the click of a button, response of an API, start of a screen, and so on...

[EDIT]
Also, try using the github version of this module, as the npm version is 2 years old, and the github version is at 29 days without an update. Install it as follow:

`npm install --save https://github.com/shaun-chiang/rn-android-pip`

Comment: I'm so sorry but I already have tried it. But it doesn't working. I don't know where should I put that codes in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you like there is an easier pilgrimage [react-native-pip-android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pip-android)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33273369)